# T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE token representation

Tags: php, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a AST builder for PHP and looking at a few grammar files for PHP I am noticing the

```
T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE
```

and my AST builder fails for HEREDOCS/NOWDOCS where the token is used. I can't seem to find a representation of that token and what kind of regex matches

Comment: You need to post the code that's causing the error, we're not mind readers.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you take a look at the PHP-Parser project, which may duplicate some of what you're trying to do here: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: @Barmar : I am writing a compiler AST builder and in other grammars they reference a T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACED token, I don't have php code that is throwing this error.

Comment: @duskwuff : I have been looking at the project among others, but I am building mine using ANTLR grammar to avoid writing in PHP

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by using quoted array keys in a double-quoted string, among other things. e.g.

```
$foo['bar'] = 'baz';
echo "$foo['bar']";
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

The proper syntaxes are:

```
echo "$foo[bar]"; // no quotes on the array key
echo "{$foo['bar']}"; // extended {} notation
```

Comment: I am looking more for the (lack of better word) regex representation of that token

Comment: good luck. you'd need to look for `['...']` in `"..."`, UNLESS they're surrounded by `{...}`.